# Change Background color of fluid page in R shiny

Tags: user-interface, shiny, background

I have a shiny fluidpage in cerulean theme with two fluidRows one within another. The first fluidRow places an image and the second fluidRow places text below the image. Below is the UI code:

```
fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),

       fluidRow(column(12,align ="center",
       div(img(src="test.png", height=200, width=300))),

    fluidRow(column(12, align = 'center', 
                    div(style = "font-size: 20px; padding: 0px 0px; margin-top:-2em"),
                    titlePanel(title = 'Express', windowTitle = 'Express Plots'))
)#closefluidRow
)#closefluidRow
) #closefluidPage
```

Here, the background color of fluidRows with the image and titlePanel is white and i would need to have a blue (cerulean color) in the background.
Could someone hint in achieving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the shinytheme just makes the text cerulean. Please try the below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
              tags$style('.container-fluid {
                             background-color: #007BA7;
              }'),

              fluidRow(column(12,align ="center",
                              div(img(src="test.png", height=200, width=300))),

                       fluidRow(column(12, align = 'center', 
                                       div(style = "font-size: 20px; padding: 0px 0px; margin-top:-2em"),
                                       titlePanel(title = 'Express', windowTitle = 'Express Plots'))
                       )#closefluidRow
              )#closefluidRow
     #closefluidPage
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You can play around with the hex colour #007BA7. I got it from [cerulean wiki](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerulean).

You could also add `background-color: #007BA7;` to a `div(style = ...)`

**Update**

Based on comment below. To limit the cerulean to the fluidPage add an id and limit the styling as below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(id = 'test',
    tags$style('#test {
                             background-color: #007BA7;
              }'),

    fluidRow(column(12,align ="center",
                    div(img(src="test.png", height=200, width=300))),

             fluidRow(column(12, align = 'center', 
                             div(style = "font-size: 20px; padding: 0px 0px; margin-top:-2em"),
                             titlePanel(title = 'Express', windowTitle = 'Express Plots'))
             )#closefluidRow
    )#closefluidRow
    #closefluidPage
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: it did changed to blue color. However, a navbarpage is present after the fluid page and the blue color is extending to the navbarpage while it is required to be only in fluidpage.

Comment: The navbarPage is not in your original example. You would need to add that so that someone can help.